# How can I help my player on the game to know where to head to?

Tags: python, pycharm

```
def main():
    inventory = []  # A list for the player to store their items
    # Dictionary of the Rooms and which directions are to be taken for each room.
    # This links one room to the other rooms.
    rooms = {
        'Lobby': {'East': 'Gym'},
        'Gym': {'West': 'Lobby', 'South': 'Pool area', 'item': 'Dumbbell'},
        'Pool area': {'North': 'Gym', 'East': 'Restaurant', 'West': 'Playroom', 'South': 'Your Room',
                      'item': 'Sunscreen'},
        'Restaurant': {'West': 'Pool area', 'North': 'Bathrooms', 'item': 'Cloth Napkin'},
        'Bathrooms': {'South': 'Restaurant', 'item': 'Toilet Roll'},
        'Playroom': {'East': 'Pool area', 'South': 'Supply Closet', 'item': 'Deck of Cards'},
        'Supply Closet': {'North': 'Playroom', 'item': 'Uniform'},
        'Your Room': {'North': 'Pool area', 'East': 'Suite', 'item': 'Laptop'},
        'Suite': {'West': 'Your Room'}}

    current_room = 'Lobby'  # Set the current room to begin the gameplay loop.
    show_menu()
    while current_room != 'Exit':  # If the current room is not the exit the user can continue to the next room.
        item = show_status(current_room, inventory, rooms)  # Displays the current room and items in inventory.
        moves = rooms[current_room]
        # The player will be prompted for which move they want to make.
        player_move = input("Enter 'go North, South, East or West' to move, or get Item, or 'Exit': ")

        if player_move == 'Exit':  # The user will exit the game.
            current_room = 'exit'
            break  # Stops the game from continuing.

        elif player_move.split()[-1] in rooms[current_room]:  # Valid command from the user.
            current_room = rooms[current_room][player_move.split()[-1]]
            # The player will move from one room to the other.

        elif player_move.split()[0].capitalize() == "Get":  # Command to collect item to inventory.
            if player_move == "get " + item:
                get_item(item, inventory, rooms, current_room)
                # The item in the current room will be put in the inventory.
                print(item, "collected")  # Tells the player that the item was collected.
            else:
                print("Invalid command")

        else:  # Set the invalid move command.
            print("Invalid Move. There's no room to the {}".format(player_move))
        print("^" * 20)  # Set separating line.

        if len(inventory) == 7:  # Amount of items required to win the game.
            print('Congratulations! You have collected all items and now can move to the Suite'
                  'to face off the politician!')
            print('You have defeated the Corrupt Politician')
            print('Thanks for playing')
            break  # The game will end after collecting all items.


main()
```

So I made this code for a class of a text based game where the player goes through different rooms and collects items. I want to help my player know which directions they can take whenever they enters the room. That way they are not guessing which way to go or a put a map.

Comment: Inside the prompt loop, print the available exits for the current room before asking for input.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Tag help experts in the topic relevant to you to reach your question, and avoid wasting time of people who are interested in certain topics. So please read the description before using them. In particular, for [`pycharm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pycharm): "DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happens to be written using PyCharm".

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I assume he wants to print only the directions that are actually valid for the current room, instead of always printing all four directions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is a bit messy, you should separate the "item" from the rooms dic so you could check if the "current_room" is in the "rooms" and find the room's choices you have to go ahead.

```py
if current_room in rooms.keys():
   print(list(rooms.get(current_room).keys())[0]) #print the direction you can go to
   current_room = list(rooms.get(current_room).values())[0] #change the rooms
   print(current_room)
```

According to the code above the player will go to the next room, but it always is the first room in the values.
For example - from "Gym" it will always go to the "Lobby", and from "Lobby" it will always go to the "Gym".
So it could stack in a loop.
You can play with the list index and randomize it so the rooms will change.

**But** before you change it you should remove the "item" from the dic, cause the code will consider "item" as a direction that can cause problems.
Good luck!